How to make work gq$ with :norm on a full text of long lines
I have this 7 lines (3 of them empty 6 very long)
Titre : *Les Ombres de la Révolution*

Dans le crépuscule d'une époque tourmentée, à l'orée d'une ville en effervescence, le vent portait les murmures de la révolte. Paris, statue de    pierre et de fer, se tenait comme un géant endormi, ses cœurs battant au rythme des aspirations et des désillusions.  Les ruelles étroites, telle  une toile d'araignée, tissaient un labyrinthe où se croisaient les âmes en quête de justice et de liberté.

Les pavés, témoins silencieux de tant de luttes, résonnaient sous les pas enfiévrés des hommes et des femmes. Parmi eux, un jeune homme, les yeux  embrasés par la passion et l'injustice, arpentait le chemin de Facile-la-Liberté. Son nom était Émile, un fils de la Révolution, éduqué dans les   idéaux de Rousseau et de Voltaire, mais déchiré par la réalité brutale d’un monde en déclin.

"Liberté, Égalité, Fraternité", ces mots lourds comme des chaînes, résonnaient en lui, tandis qu’il réfléchissait à l’avenir incertain qui         l'attendait. Émile savait que la lutte pour ces idéaux dépassait les simples discours : elle exigait du sacrifice et du courage. Dans le tumulte   de la ville, il voyait se profiler l'ombre de la guerre, menaçante comme un orage, prête à déchirer le tissu fragile de la société.

From a selection ggvG I want to format this with :'<,'>norm gq$
It kind of work, but not all lines are formated, in fact only the 7 first, because the first line to be formated produce 5 lines, I get this:
Titre : *Les Ombres de la Révolution*

Dans le crépuscule d'une époque tourmentée, à l'orée d'une ville en effervescence, le
vent portait les murmures de la révolte. Paris, statue de pierre et de fer, se tenait
comme un géant endormi, ses cœurs battant au rythme des aspirations et des désillusions.
Les ruelles étroites, telle une toile d'araignée, tissaient un labyrinthe où se
croisaient les âmes en quête de justice et de liberté.

Les pavés, témoins silencieux de tant de luttes, résonnaient sous les pas enfiévrés des hommes et des femmes. Parmi eux, un jeune homme, les yeux embrasés par la passion et l'injustice, arpentait le chemin de Facile-la-Liberté. Son nom était Émile, un fils de la Révolution, éduqué dans les idéaux de Rousseau et de Voltaire, mais déchiré par la réalité brutale d’un monde en déclin.

"Liberté, Égalité, Fraternité", ces mots lourds comme des chaînes, résonnaient en lui, tandis qu’il réfléchissait à l’avenir incertain qui l'attendait. Émile savait que la lutte pour ces idéaux dépassait les simples discours : elle exigait du sacrifice et du courage. Dans le tumulte de la ville, il voyait se profiler l'ombre de la guerre, menaçante comme un orage, prête à déchirer le tissu fragile de la société.

I would like to get this:
Titre : *Les Ombres de la Révolution*

Dans le crépuscule d'une époque tourmentée, à l'orée d'une ville en effervescence, le
vent portait les murmures de la révolte. Paris, statue de pierre et de fer, se tenait
comme un géant endormi, ses cœurs battant au rythme des aspirations et des désillusions.
Les ruelles étroites, telle une toile d'araignée, tissaient un labyrinthe où se
croisaient les âmes en quête de justice et de liberté.

Les pavés, témoins silencieux de tant de luttes, résonnaient sous les pas enfiévrés des 
hommes et des femmes. Parmi eux, un jeune homme, les yeux embrasés par la passion et
l'injustice, arpentait le chemin de Facile-la-Liberté. Son nom était Émile, un fils de
la Révolution, éduqué dans les idéaux de Rousseau et de Voltaire, mais déchiré par la
réalité brutale d’un monde en déclin.

"Liberté, Égalité, Fraternité", ces mots lourds comme des chaînes, résonnaient en lui, 
tandis qu’il réfléchissait à l’avenir incertain qui l'attendait. Émile savait que la
lutte pour ces idéaux dépassait les simples discours : elle exigait du sacrifice et du
courage. Dans le tumulte de la ville, il voyait se profiler l'ombre de la guerre,
menaçante comme un orage, prête à déchirer le tissu fragile de la société.


You might want to explain why you want to use :[range]normal gqq instead of gggqG or ggVGgq: as is, I think using those would be the easiest option, and rather than assume you didn’t know them I figured I’d assume there’s some (as yet unstated) reason you won’t.

Root cause seems to be that marks are only updated after the command finishes. Another reason to avoid Visual mode if possible. FWIW, I'd go by paragraph and do gggq4}.

When I face this problem, I add additional empty lines to my selection as a workaround.

Welcome to Vi and Vim! I edited to avoid the phrase "I have the same problem". Sorry, but that's usually a telltale for something not being an answer. Feel free to [edit] and improve further or undo my changes.
